# Traces of Screen on closing of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i have been using #drawer layout# , I have created basic sample application which works fine on tablets and high end mobile phones ,but when run on low end phone like micromax A89 and LAVA iris502 the screen leaves behind traces of the UI even when the slider has been closed.

but the same app works well on the tablet with similar specs

why is this happening ?? thanx in advance

--> Since I m not able to send you image of traces of UI on screen so I m making my display pic with same i hope it will help to catch problem..

Comment: could you please take a screenshot please?

Comment: I was not able to send Screen shot because i have less reputation point so I kept that image as my Display Pic.